# How to build a PDC connected to Open DIrectory on OS X 10.6

Tags: windows-7, samba, mac-osx-server, opendirectory, osx-snow-leopard

Since OS X Server has an older version of Samba that cannot be used with Windows 7, I want to setup a newer (3.5.5) Samba server as a PDC.  I want to continue to use Open Directory on the 10.6 OS X Server to keep account information.  Has anyone done this and what steps are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller and http://www.virtualbox.org/. Both are free. Set up the windows domain controller as an LDAP replica/slave to the Open Directory server.

Comment: I guess I need to clarify.  My main problem is that I am not sure how to setup the smb.conf on the PDC to interface correctly with the 10.6 box.  It seems Open Directory has some quirks over a normal LDAP setup.